# Why is this not summing each column's values on input field change?

Tags: javascript, html

Beginner question here:
As the user changes the input value, the column total should change, but I see the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementsByTagName')`

```js
function updateColumnTotals(colIndex) {
  const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableRows');
  const rows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  let total = 0;
  console.log("Column Index: " + colIndex)

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const row = rows[i];
    const cell = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[colIndex];
    const input = cell.querySelector('.size_qty');

    if (input) {
      const value = parseFloat(input.value) || 0;
      total += value;
    }
  }

  // Update the total row in the table for the specified column
  const totalRow = tableBody.getElementsByClassName('column-total-row')[0];
  const totalCell = totalRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[colIndex];
  totalCell.innerHTML = `<strong>${total.toFixed(2)}</strong>`;
}

// Use the DOMContentLoaded event listener to ensure the DOM is fully loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const sizeQtyInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".size_qty");
  sizeQtyInputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener("change", function() {
      const colIndex = Array.from(input.parentNode.parentNode.cells).indexOf(input.parentNode);
      updateColumnTotals(colIndex);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:4%">L</th>
      <th style="width:4%">XL</th>
      <th style="width:4%">2XL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableRows">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="50" onchange="updateColumnTotals(1)"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="50" onchange="updateColumnTotals(2)"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="25" onchange="updateColumnTotals(3)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="40" onchange="updateColumnTotals(1)"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="15" onchange="updateColumnTotals(2)"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="5" onchange="updateColumnTotals(3)"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column-total-row" align="middle"><strong>10</strong></td>
      <td class="column-total-row" align="middle"><strong>0</strong></td>
      <td class="column-total-row" align="middle"><strong>600</strong></td>
      <td class="total_title" align="middle"></td>
      <td id="totalValue" class="total"><strong></strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `tbody` tags and you tried to load the summary from the first `tbody`. You also created the events twice. First as an `onchange` in the tag and then via `addEventListener`. Finally, you passed values of 1, 2, 3 instead of 0, 1, 2. Applied fixed to your code and now it seems to be working.

```js
function updateColumnTotals(colIndex) {
  const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableRows');
  const summaryBody = document.getElementById('summaryRows');
  const rows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const row = rows[i];
    const cell = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[colIndex];
    const input = cell.querySelector('.size_qty');

    if (input) {
      const value = parseFloat(input.value) || 0;
      total += value;
    }
  }
  

  // Update the total row in the table for the specified column
  const totalRow = summaryBody.getElementsByClassName('column-total-row')[colIndex];
  const totalCell = totalRow.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0];
  totalCell.innerHTML = `<strong>${total.toFixed(2)}</strong>`;
}

// Use the DOMContentLoaded event listener to ensure the DOM is fully loaded
/*document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const sizeQtyInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".size_qty");
  sizeQtyInputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener("change", function() {
      const colIndex = Array.from(input.parentNode.parentNode.cells).indexOf(input.parentNode);
      updateColumnTotals(colIndex - 1);
    });
  });
});*/
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:4%">L</th>
      <th style="width:4%">XL</th>
      <th style="width:4%">2XL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableRows">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="50" onchange="updateColumnTotals(0)"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="50" onchange="updateColumnTotals(1)"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="25" onchange="updateColumnTotals(2)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="40" onchange="updateColumnTotals(0)"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="15" onchange="updateColumnTotals(1)"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="5" onchange="updateColumnTotals(2)"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <tbody id="summaryRows">
    <tr>
      <td class="column-total-row" align="middle"><strong>10</strong></td>
      <td class="column-total-row" align="middle"><strong>0</strong></td>
      <td class="column-total-row" align="middle"><strong>600</strong></td>
      <td class="total_title" align="middle"></td>
      <td id="totalValue" class="total"><strong></strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What an oversight. Anyway, still learning and I didn't explicitly create the 2 `tbody`. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `tableBody` variable is the first `<tbody>`, and your `column-total-row` td's are part of the second `<tbody>`.  The error message tells you all of this, and even points to the bad line.

You need to add an `id` to the second `<tbody>` so you can search through it.